# How can I click buttons in a windows GUI program using python?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am writing a python script that automates running a program and performing different tasks within the program. My main problem is figuring out how to click buttons and interact with the GUI of the program to be controlled.

I am currently using the pyautogui library and using pyautogui.click(X,Y) to advance through prompts and click on different menus and menu items. The problem with this approach is that I am relying on a separate script to inform me of the coordinates of interest in my environment by telling me the coordinates of where my cursor is hovering. This probably will not work on other machines and just seems like a one case solution.

My question is how can I automate using a program in windows (clicking around) without having to hard code the exact position of the items I need to click?

For example, If I need to click a "ok" box to accept some setting, how can I make Windows grab the program window, read through the options and click what I need without any prior knowledge of the position of the dialog box and where the "Ok" button is located?

Code:

```
import pyautogui as gui

gui.click(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you can do this using pyautogui is with their locating methods. You will need a picture (for example of the OK box) and then you can have pyautogui find it on the screen and give you its coordinates. Check out the official [documentation on this](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions).